# DotNetOpenAuth and Windows Azure with MVC3 Web Role

Tags: azure, web-config, dotnetopenauth

I have created a cloud project with an MVC3 webrole (empty project, added homecontroller and view). When I debug(F5) it runs smoothly.

After installing DotNetOpenAuth 3.4.7.11121 via NuGet I get the following error:

> Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio There was an error
>   attaching the debugger to the IIS worker process for URL
>   'http://127.255.0.1:83/' for role instance
>   'deployment16(82).WindowsAzureProject1.MvcWebRole1_IN_0'. Unable to
>   start debugging on the web server. See help for common configuration
>   errors. Running the web page outside of the debugger may provide
>   further information. Make sure the server is operating correctly.
>   Verify there are no syntax errors in web.config by doing a Debug.Start
>   Without Debugging. You may also want to refer to the ASP.NET and ATL
>   Server debugging topic in the online documentation.

Same thing happens on an MVC2 project on another machine.
Boils down to the following line of configSections in web.config (added by install-package DotNetOpenAuth)

```
<section name="uri" type="System.Configuration.UriSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

What am I missing?

Seems like the mentioned line above from web.config can be deleted. Probably already included in machine.config or something.

And, when i hit debug on the mvc project it runs as expected. The error only happens when i debug the cloud project

Comment: What happens if you "Run | Start without Debugging" on the cloud project?

Comment: Running without debugging results in a 500 internal server error on the cloud project.

Comment: I spent about 3 hours debugging this same exact issue and your solution fixed it! Thanks =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like deleting the mentioned line (`section name="uri"...`) fixes things in both debug and without debug.

I have not discovered any ill effects and logon with OpenID against Google with dotNetOpenAuth works.

Comment: .NET doesn't like it when you define sections twice.  Unfortunately it seems that Azure has a non-standard machine.config file (or it's running .NET 4.0, which also has machine.config this way).  Your fix is appropriate.